# How can i import the Extension Attributes from Azure Active Directory from Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

When I do the connection with portal Azure in portal in PowerShell for Import de data users as CSV i do this:

C:\Users\Get-AzADUser

Then, the PowerShell performs de download of a large amount of attributes for each user.
However, I don't see the AD "Extension attributes" being imported into the CSV.

[image]

How can I extract the information from the "extension attributes" part and attach it to the other columns that are imported?
Does any method in PowerShell for performing what I want?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: To fetch the **`onPremisesExtensionAttributes`** you have to make use of Microsoft Graph/Mg Graph module as  `onPremisesExtensionAttributes` is the property in Microsoft Graph. Refer this by [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220032/is-it-possible-to-list-extensionattribute1-extensionattribute15-via-powershell)  by Joy Wang.

Make use of below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"

# select the properties you want to import
$users = Get-MgUser -Property id,displayName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes

# Export ExtensionAttribute based on your requiremement. I am exporting only three extension attributes (you can export till 15)
$users | Select-Object Id, DisplayName, @{Name="ExtensionAttribute1";Expression={$_.onPremisesExtensionAttributes.extensionAttribute1}}, @{Name="ExtensionAttribute2";Expression={$_.onPremisesExtensionAttributes.extensionAttribute2}}, @{Name="ExtensionAttribute3";Expression={$_.onPremisesExtensionAttributes.extensionAttribute3}} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\rukmini\Downloads\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

*In the Portal for sample, the Extension attribute is like below:*

[image]

***The CSV file with the user information and Extension attributes exported successfully:***

[image]